# Ubuntu 13.10 installer/live fails to boot from USB with exfat partition

Tags: boot, live-usb, exfat

i can't boot ubuntu LIVE/INSTALLER from usb stick with exFat Partition, anyone know how add support for exfat in a live CD/USB?

Comment: As far as I know exfat support is not yet built into Linux (Uvuntu). It will need someone with deep knowledge of Ubuntu boot system and exfat partition to create what you are asking for. It may be easier to stick to FAT32 for now (and use a smaller USB drive). You may have to wait a few years for exFat to be fully baked into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I personally find that the best way to create a Ubuntu Live USB is to use Unetbootin. You can download it here:

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

SOURCE: I'm typing this from Ubuntu running on a USB that was created with Unetbootin ;)